# How do I create a secure authentication service which works both for web apps and mobile apps?

Tags: authentication, web-application, web-browser, mobile, web-service

As far as I am aware the best way to securely store session data on a client is to use an HTTP-only, secure cookie + HTTPS on a browser and to store a (JWT) token in a secure place for a mobile app.

Let's assume I want to create a standard web service using REST principles, how would one go about it?
When calling the login API endpoint, should the service reply with both the Set-Cookie header containing the session and the authentication token for the mobile app? Should the logins be separated API endpoints maybe?

How about validating the session for each API endpoint, should both the Authorization HTTP header and the session be checked for valid user data?

Comment: Authentication frameworks exist for this, e.g. [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html).

Comment: I know they exist, but how do they solve this problem?